# Shell Script, move each 2 files to each directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have 10 files from 1.txt to 10.txt and 5 folders a b c d e

I want to move my files in this way :

```
1.txt 2.txt to a
3.txt 4.txt to b
..
..
9.txt 10.txt to e
```

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you have tried thus far?  This is a pretty broad and non-specific question that will surely get closed since it does not fall within [the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for how to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Buggabill I'd consider this a general coding issue, and within the guidelines.  I'd guess it's an opinion on how you interpret the "homework" rule, and certainly it would be improved by the OP's addition on what he/she thought would work.

Comment: Please add your trials and errors in a [MCVE]

Comment: Thank you guys, next time I post some code

Comment: @SaintHax - This is a "gimme-the-codez" type of question as it shows no attempt at trying to solve the problem.  FirstStep has linked to a pretty relevant page regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the commands to do it.

```
count=0    # initialize the counter
declare -a files=(*.txt)     # put all the txt files in an array
# just print directories, and strip the unneeded /. in the returned string
declare -a dirs=($(ls -d */.|sed 's;/.;;')

# run through the array, moving each file
while [[ $count -le ${#files[@]} ]]; do
    mv ${files[$count]} ${dirs[$(($count/2))]}  
    ((++count))    # very important to increment the counters
done
```

The hard to read part is taking each file, and then moving it to the directory with the half that index.  Since bash math rounds down and ignores remainders, this will give us index 0, 0, 1, 1, and so forth.